# Google Awareness API SecurityException is thrown

Tags: android, google-awareness

I'm using [DetectedActivityFence](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/awareness/fence/DetectedActivityFence) from [Google Awareness API](https://developers.google.com/awareness/). It's working fine on my own devices, but I received a several crashes in Crashlytics about **SecurityException**.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid API Key for package = [package_name] .Status code received = -1
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzu$zza$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd.zzqz(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpw$zzc.zzapl(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpw$zzf.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzrn.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This happened without any correlations between Android versions, i.e. it affects devices from different manufacturers and different Android versions(5.x-6.x). These devices aren't rooted and look like working on Stock ROM. This problem appears for 10% of my users.

I'm sure that I'm using the right API key otherwise I can see the crash on my own device, can I?

Did anybody face the same issue?

Comment: have you create API key in google console?

Comment: @Amy yes, it works on my devices and I assume the key is right.

Comment: @aeinsam The *API Key* which you generated with whichever *package name* the *package name* is differ. I mean check the package name of your app and which one you entered on developer console while generating *API Key*.

Comment: @jaydroider checked, it's the same I'm using in my app.

Comment: @aeinsam, I'm seeing the same behaviour: works on all debug and release builds in house, for some users out there Crashlytics reports the SecurityException seen above. Have you been able to fix the issue?

Comment: @FlorianBarth no, I removed that feature from my application. Do you know where I can submit a bug related to Play Services?

Comment: I reported the issue to the AOSP issue tracker, I hope that was the right one or they can give a hint on the right bug tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223751

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bug that erroneously mistakes some errors from the network operation to authenticate the app as indicating that the API key was not set up correctly, even though the actual error was something else.  This has been fixed internally and will roll out in the next Google Play services release.

For now, the best workaround is to add an UncaughtExceptionHandler on the thread that calls GoogleApiClient.connect().  If you call GoogleApiClient.connect() on the main thread, then you can get the Thread instance via Looper.myLooper().getThread().

Comment: Fix will be rolling out in early 2017.

Comment: how do you know that?

Comment: Seems to be paraphrased from a bug report. I have created a new answer that is properly referenced. It is important to keep an eye on that thread and make updates there. From what I read, there is disagreement as to whether that "best workaround" even works. Downvote for not attributing your source.

Comment: @mklimek: mochu was my colleague at Google on the Awareness API.

Comment: Is this bug fixed?

Answer (score 0):

From: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223751#c2

> There is a bug in our checks that is sometimes throwing this
>   SecurityException when there is a network error to authenticate.  The
>   fix will rollout in the next version of Google Play services.
>
> For now, the best workaround would be set up an
>   UncaughtExceptionHandler on the thread that you call
>   GoogleApiClient.connect().  For most folks, this would be on the main
>   thread, which you can get via Looper.myLooper().getThread().

But you will also notice that replies indicate that is not a solid work around.

You may also notice that the OP of that thread references this SO post, but the accepted answer doesn't back reference the thread, even though they copied from it verbatim. Very bad form!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue as i was getting the same error, and i thought it might be the Awareness API keys not syncing to the Google Developer Console, after lots of looking and getting the same error, I went back to the Awareness API on Google Developer Console and realized my Awareness API was not enabled even though, I had the package set and had a valid API key. Also make sure that API key is set in your Manifest. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled almost a day and found another answer. Although accepted answer was correct at that time.

The only thing helped me that is generating API key on Google Developer Console using debug keystore for testing purpose and replacing same with release keystore while going to production.

How generate API key? Please check out Google's word itself [Here](https://developers.google.com/awareness/android-api/get-a-key)

Hope it will help someone in future.